# In distributed tensorflow, how to write to summary from workers as well

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am using google cloud ml distributed sample for training a model on a cluster of computers. Input and output (ie rfrecords, checkpoints, tfevents) are all on gs:// (google storage)

Similarly to the distributed sample, I use an evaluation step that is called at the end, and the result is written as a summary, in order to use parameter hypertuning / either within Cloud ML, or using my own stack of tools.

But rather than performing a single evaluation on a large batch of data, I am running several evaluation steps, in order to retrieve statistics on the performance criteria, because I don't want to limited to a single value. I want to get information regarding the performance interval. In particular, the variance of performance is important to me. I'd rather select a model with lower average performance but with better worst cases.

I therefore run several evaluation steps. What I would like to do is to parallelize these evaluation steps because right now, only the master is evaluating. When using large clusters, it is a source of inefficiency, and task workers to evaluate as well.

Basically, the supervisor is created as :

```
self.sv = tf.train.Supervisor(
            graph,
            is_chief=self.is_master,
            logdir=train_dir(self.args.output_path),
            init_op=init_op,
            saver=self.saver,
            # Write summary_ops by hand.
            summary_op=None,
            global_step=self.tensors.global_step,
            # No saving; we do it manually in order to easily evaluate immediately
            # afterwards.
            save_model_secs=0)
```

At the end of training I call the summary writer. :

```
            # only on master, this is what I want to remove
            if self.is_master and not self.should_stop:

                # I want to have an idea of statistics of accuracy
                # not just the mean, hence I run on 10 batches

                for i in range(10):
                    self.global_step += 1

                    # I call an evaluator, and extract the accuracy 
                    evaluation_values = self.evaluator.evaluate()
                    accuracy_value = self.model.accuracy_value(evaluation_values)

                    # now I dump the accuracy, ready to use within hptune
                    eval_summary = tf.Summary(value=[
                        tf.Summary.Value(
                            tag='training/hptuning/metric', simple_value=accuracy_value)
                    ])

                    self.sv.summary_computed(session, eval_summary, self.global_step)
```

I tried to write summaries from workers as well , but I got an error : basically summary can be written from masters only. Is there any easy way to workaround ? The error is : `"Writing a summary requires a summary writer."`

Comment: Can you post the error message you're seeing?

Comment: You might have to use `sess.run(eval_summary)`. In the current, it looks like the summary writer should have been initialized when you created the supervisor. Could you try to add `summary_writer=tf.train.Supervisor.USE_DEFAULT` to see if that changes anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you'd create a separate summary writer on each worker yourself, and write out summaries directly rather.

I suspect you wouldn't use a supervisor for the eval processing either. Just load a session on each worker for doing eval with the latest checkpoint, and writing out independent summaries.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactely what I did. I just needed to take care of the synchronisation : the model might not be saved yet.... Is there any way of communicating between the master and the workers - for instance is the "global_step" a shared variable ?

Comment: No there isn't a way to communicate out of box... You could use something like a gcs object to communicate status. Example a manifest file for a checkpoint that eval workers look at.